# Spring boot + hikari - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I get the following error trying to start my Spring application

`ERROR 5908 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.`

My `application.properties` file looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.one.jdbc-url = jdbc:postgresql://10.x.x.x:y/sampledb1
spring.datasource.one.username = someuser
spring.datasource.one.password = somepasswd
spring.datasource.one.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.two.jdbc-url = jdbc:postgresql://10.x.x.x:z/sampledb2
spring.datasource.two.username = someuser
spring.datasource.two.password = somepassword
spring.datasource.two.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
```

And I am using DataSourceBuilder class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig
{
    @Bean(name = "one")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.one") 
    public DataSource dataSource1()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "two")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.two") 
    public DataSource dataSource2()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

My pom looks like this.

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.powermock>1.6.2</version.powermock>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- actuator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- eureka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hystrix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>
```

This was working fine earlier, but now causing some issues. And the error occurs `intermittently`, sometime it starts without error, other times it fails with the error.

I tried solutions suggested in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname) .They don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I try to using your code with H2 db...it's working without problem.

Comment: Ya it works intermittently. But sometimes it fails.

Comment: @user2761431 Did you manage to get it working? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

Change `jdbc-url` to `jdbcUrl` so [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/README.md) can find suitable driver per url.

> **jdbcUrl**
>   This property directs HikariCP to use "DriverManager-based" configuration. We feel that DataSource-based configuration (above) is superior for a variety of reasons (see below), but for many deployments there is little significant difference. When using this property with "old" drivers, you may also need to set the driverClassName property, but try it first without. Note that if this property is used, you may still use DataSource properties to configure your driver and is in fact recommended over driver parameters specified in the URL itself. Default: none

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when spring looks for the properties file at the wrong location. For example, when the Java option `-Dspring.config.location=...` is passed to your application server at startup then your properties file of your deployed application is ignored - even if there is no properties file at `spring.config.location`, too.