# Spring Boot error with multiple data-sources :: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, datasource, database-connectivity

I can see following error in my Intellij local for sometime now.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.**

I have multiple data-sources configured for my project. Something similar as given below.

```
dataSource-1:
  driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jdbc-url: so-and-so

datasource-2:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: so-and-so
```

As you notice above, somewhere I'm using driverClassName, somewhere the 3 words are separated by hyphens.

So do I need to maintain the same standard in Spring-boot 2.0 across the entire yml file?

By standard, I mean,

- **driverClassName word would be the same in all places (driver-class-name)**
- jdbc-url/url text also need to be the same **jdbcUrl in all places**

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455426/spring-boot-hikari-datasource-or-datasourceclassname-or-jdbcurl-is-required) in stackOverFlow discusses the same.

Please note, the hikari-config setter methods read the values properly in all the config classes wherever they are used, no issues with that.

Any help would be welcome.