# Spring Boot Hikari configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm configuring HikariCP for Spring Boot application, the database is Postgresql.

The [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) says:
"We recommended using `dataSourceClassName` instead of `jdbcUrl`, but either is acceptable."

However, the next line says:
"Note: Spring Boot auto-configuration users, you need to use `jdbcUrl`-based configuration."

If we use `jdbcUrl`-based configuration and specify `dataSourceClassName` then `jdbcUrl` will be ignored, if we don't specify data source -  `HikariDataSource` will be created. So they recommend using `HikariDataSource` for Spring Boot apps.

If we use `dataSourceClassName` - it will be created with given properties (in my case it is `PGSimpleDataSource` with its ancestor `BaseDataSource`).

Both these configurations work for me.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the difference between `HikariDataSource` and `PGSimpleDataSource` (or any other recommended)?
2. Why it is recommended to use `jdbcUrl`-based configuration (and thus `HikariDataSource`) in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is a connection pool, and a very good one. We've been using it in several projects in production and it's fast and just works.
2. If you want to use HikariCP you use `HikariDataSource`. Spring Boot has started to use it as a default and recommends it (for the same reasons: it's fast and solid).

If you just use the default configuration with `spring.datasource.url`, it will use HikariCP and should work out-of-the-box.

However, when you manually configure your datasource(s), there is a small issue with Spring Boot 2 and HikariCP. HikariCP expects `jdbcUrl` or `dataSourceClassName`, but the Spring Boot configuration property uses `url`. 
See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname) for that.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable for me, but why do they have different DataSources recommendations for Spring Boot and other apps, while providing all of them in a package?