# How to configure mutiple DataSource with driver-class in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mariadb

Why is the driverclass missing in the following configuration?

```
spring.datasource.testdb.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/mytable
spring.datasource.testdb.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testdb.username=test
spring.datasource.testdb.password=test


@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.testdb")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSourceTest() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateTest() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceTest());
    }

    //secondary db config to follow
}

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Result:

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to
>   determine a suitable driver class

This is strange, because I can even step into the `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` class, so it is clearly on classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add the @Bean annotation to dataSourceTest().

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.testdb")
@Primary
```

Also, for the Hikari connection pool (which is the default connection pool), the url property is jdbc-url, not url. So change

```
spring.datasource.testdb.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/mytable
```

to

```
spring.datasource.testdb.jdbc-url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/mytable
```

For more info, and other possible solutions see: [After Spring Boot 2.0 migration: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried, and the app then starts successfully. BUT on access of `JdbcTemplate` I then get: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.*

Comment: I modified the answer to also change the url property to jdbc-url.

Comment: Indeed especially the following answer seems to provide the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141541/1194415

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the properties file is being loaded correctly? The message clearly specifies that the `url` attribute was not specified, so apparently the `spring.datasource.testdb.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/mytable` line is not being read - the driver classpath has nothing to do with it.

The lines should be in an `application.properties` file by default, is that where you have them?

Comment: Yes it's in `application.properties`. If I remove the `DataSourceConfig` and change the configuration to one primary ds only, eg `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/mytable`, everything works as expected. So in general the setup should be fine. Just the mutiple ds config not...