# Why is Environment variable always null when reading from properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to using `application.properties` and am struggling because Environment is always null. I have followed numerous examples such as the accepted answer shown on SO [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname); however, I keep getting the error message showing below. This is a Spring application and I know I don't actually need to go through this manual process per the article [HERE](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/). However, I have to show how to connect manually using the properties file. Where am I going wrong? Effectively, I want to hide my database credentials in application.properties and then read them into something like `DriverManager.getConnection(env.getProperty("URL"), env.getProperty("USERNAME", env.getProperty("PASSWORD");`

Attempting to use Environment:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class OpenConnection {
    private volatile Connection con;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    public OpenConnection() {
    }

    @Bean
    public Connection getInstance() {
        try {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            handleException(e);
        }

        return con;
    }
```

application.properties

```
# MySQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rentalportfolio?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.crd.carrental.database.connectionoperations.OpenConnection.getInstance(OpenConnection.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.crd.carrental.database.selectoperations.SelectExistingReservation.<init>(SelectExistingReservation.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.crd.carrental.controllers.ExistingReservationController.lookupReservationId(ExistingReservationController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:565) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:511) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:94) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:520) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:454) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144) [spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_261]
```

Comment: If you are using spring boot I would recommend letting spring configure the connection:spring.datasource.driverClassName=${JDBC_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME}, spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, spring.datasource.password in application.properties

Comment: @LuisAcero I just edited my post to show my application.properties file. I am not sure how to implement what you're suggesting though?

Comment: Ditch your configuration and let spring boot take care of the `DataSource`. You are currently working around that, nor is this the correct way to obtain a JDBC connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are using `@Component` on your OpenConnection rather than `@Configuration`

[Here](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/) you can find some more examples, how to use properties in your Spring application

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing this `OpenConnection` class and let SpringBoot create your datasource for you on start up.

If you really want to create it yourself, check the docs. Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ChrisSavory. I need to create it myself though. I just can't figure out how to read from my application.properties file. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Yes, i just showed you how in my answer. Does it work?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! What is "spring.datasource" in this case?

Comment: Those are all your properties in your yaml or properties files.  E.g. `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`

Comment: You really need to read through this section. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource