# Bean not getting provided from ConfigurationProperties with prefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I enhanced Application class as a Configuration class and also marked it a @Component so that the provided values can be Autowired in the using code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class BinancebotApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="chartpatternsignal.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

I tried autowire the above DataSource:

```
@Configuration
public class ChartPatternSignalDaoImpl {
  @Qualifier("chartpatternsignal")
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;
```

In my pom.xml I have used the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

But it is not working:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at
> least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="chartpatternsignal"),
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
>
> Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling   `@Qualifier("chartpatternsignal")` , however your Datasource is not named that.

It would be   `@Qualifier("primaryDataSource")`

Try:

```
@Component
public class ChartPatternSignalDaoImpl {

  @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;
```

or:

```
@Configuration
public class BinancebotConfiguration  {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("myLovelyDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="chartpatternsignal.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

Then autowrite it by qualifier:

```
  @Qualifier("myLovelyDataSource")
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;
```

---

The Springboot Documentation showcases how to create a `DataSource` using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access

---

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class BinancebotApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


}
```

---

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

---

Service Class

```
@Service
public class BinanceService {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;

}
```

---

application.properties

```
app.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
app.datasource.username=sa
app.datasource.pool-size=30
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use create the Qualifier correctly in the Configuration class, but I'm getting a new exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.".
With a single data source I had configured with 
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.springboot.sqlite.SQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true

but apparently these are not getting picked up when I use a custom data source name. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname